# Configure DB2 LDAP authentication

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, ldap, db2

I want to configure LDAP auth in DB2. From IBM [docs](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/t0056291.html) I learned that first I need to configure LDAP authentication in operating system. But in documentation described *old* way of configuring LDAP for Operating system. RedHat recommends to use only new SSSD tool.

So, I configured it using SSSD (but without SSL, setting `FORCELEGACY` parameter in *authconfig*  file to `YES`). Now I can login to system as LDAP user.

But one of the step (step *1.e*) in IBM docs assumes that we use old way of LDAP configuring (I think so). So I can't properly configure LDAP authentication in DB2.

Can anyone help me to configure LDAP auth on DB2 9.7 when we use SSSD?  I use CentOS 6.3.

Answer (score 1):

For the next user that needs to do this, the correct answer is, if you are using sssd for ldap, then

inside the /etc/pam.d/db2 file created as part of the IBM directions, replace "pam_ldap.so" with "pam_sss.so" and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

It Depend how you can configured your ldap auth, if you set FORCELEGACY=yes in /etc/sysconfig/authconfig and your system will uses the redhat 5 configuration mode, this file /etc/sysconfig/authconfig is for authconfig command, so if you are using sssd, maybe you configured by hand or you got FORCELEGACY=no (default in redhat 6)

The link below can help you, anyway if you give more information about what problem you found, configuring sssd, we can try to help you

Sorry for the external link http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-enterprise-47/rhel-6-ldap-now-requires-tls-843917/